# Can Chill Touch prevent Regeneration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, regeneration

**Can the D&D 5th Edition cantrip *Chill Touch* prevent regeneration and similar abilities?**

**Do specific forms of regeneration (like a troll's) circumvent this?**

*Chill Touch:*

> You create a ghostly, skeletal hand in the space of a creature within
> range. Make a ranged spell attack against the creature to assail it
> with the chill of the grave. On a hit, the target takes 1d8 necrotic
> damage, ***and it can't regain hit points until the start of your next
> turn***. Until then, the hand clings to the target.

*Troll rule text:*

> The troll regains 10 Hit Points at the start of its turn. ***If the troll
> takes acid or fire damage***, this trait doesn't function at the start of
> the troll's next turn. The troll dies only if it starts its turn with
> 0 Hit Points and doesn't Regenerate.

(emphasis mine)

Here is the [now-unofficial ruling from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/712341784186085376).

I can't tell if this is a classic case of specific-vs-general or just designer intent being unclear in RAW.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, *chill touch* prevents regeneration.  The spell's text says that the target can't regain hit points, and there's nothing in the text of the troll's regeneration feature that contradicts that.  Just because the trait doesn't function if the troll takes acid or fire damage doesn't mean that's the *only* condition under which the trait doesn't function; saying otherwise is [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: If the troll is at full HP its not going to gain more and it wont fall over dead. The regen is still in effect, it just does not gain HP for the round.

Comment: A great example of something similar is that spells such as *darkness* do not say that *dispel magic* ends them, but clearly it does

Comment: Another way to read it is the troll regeneration adds an extra effect to Acid and Fire damage, namely, prevent its regeneration. The regeneration ability doesn't bypass other things that explicitly prevent regeneration.  If the ability says "Only Fire and Acid can prevent this regeneration", then it'll be different.

Answer (score 6):

### Only partially, and not permanently.

Regeneration here has three effects:

1. The troll regains 10 Hit Points at the start of its turn.
2. If the troll takes acid or fire damage, this trait doesn't function at the start of the troll's next turn.
3. The troll dies only if it starts its turn with 0 Hit Points and doesn't Regenerate.

*Chill touch* directly prevents 1 as stated, but it neither fulfills 2 nor otherwise prevents 3.

The net effect is that, absent acid or fire damage, the troll won’t regain hit points until it’s no longer under the effects of *chill touch*, and will then start regaining hit points.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Chill Touch will kill the troll. The Regeneration trait doesn't state that it can *only* be stopped by fire or acid damage, it only says that that's *one method* of stopping it. Therefore, your point 2) is irrelevant, as Chill Touch also prevents regenerating hit points. Taking this into accoutn, 3) is fulfilled, if the troll has 0 HP and took damage from Chill Touch during that round.

Comment: @PixelMaster 3 does not say “doesn’t regain hit points”. It says “doesn’t Regenerate”.

Comment: You raise an interesting point, but you could certainly interpret "Regenerate" as meaning "regain hit points".  i.e. if this race feature has an effect this turn, it prevents death.   It would make sense for the troll to killable if anything stops its healing.  Your interpretation can't be ruled out, it also seems like a plausible intent and also compatible with the phrasing.  But I didn't upvote this answer.

Comment: How do you think this answer could be improved, then?

Comment: I am not sure that rules were even intended to make "Regenerate = regain hit points". Flavour-wise, fire or acid damage destroys the troll, while Chill Touch simply stalls his recovery. I agree with this answer.